# Determine Collection type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I've a function whose header looks like this

```
func doSomethingOnCollection<T:Collection>(_ array: T) -> [T]
```

as you can see it takes Collection as a parameter, meaning it can be Array, Set or Dictionary, how can I check type of parameter passed in this function at runtime ?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Hamish I wan to sort my collection types by calling a generic function which will take Collection as input as return sorted Array

Comment: That doesn't explain why you want to "*check type of parameter passed in this function at runtime*" though – the whole point of generics is that you shouldn't have to do this kind of runtime type-checking.

Comment: @Hamish instead of writing different type of function for each Collection Type I want to write a generic function that will work on any type of collection even for customs one's

Comment: @Zubair, `that will work on any type of collection even for customs one's` — how will this work if you will manually check type of collection inside?

Comment: @user28434 @Hamish I was not clear about that in the beginning, then sorted it out, here is the final header of the function that I defined
`func doSomethingOnCollection <T:Collection>(collection items:T) -> [Int] where T.Iterator.Element == Int, T.SubSequence: Collection, T.SubSequence.SubSequence == T.SubSequence, T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) says:

> Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a
>   certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the
>   instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

```
func doSomethingOnCollection<T: Collection>(_ param: T) -> [T] {
    if param is Array<Any> {
        print("Array")
    }
    // We can't say 'Set<Any>', since type of set should conform
    // protocol 'Hashable'
    else if param is Set<Int> {
        print("Set")
    }
    // For the same reason above, we can't say 'Dictionary<Any, Any>'
    else if param is Dictionary<Int, Any> {
        print("Dictionary")
    }
    return []
}
```